# json extract keys without knowing variable data

Tags: javascript, json

just started with json. I have something similar to this data (this data is called Data0012.json and I cant edit it or change the -162.65 to another thing ... also ... that first data, changes, so I cant call it):

```
{
    "-162.65": {
        "Player": "DntFuckwithMeMTFrs",
        "Hands": "44",
        "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)": "13",
        "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100": "-162.65",
        "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)": "50"
    },
    "-162.27": {
        "Player": "paramasivum",
        "Hands": "40",
        "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)": "9",
        "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100": "-162.27",
        "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)": "67"
    },
    "-157.32": {
        "Player": "Fairline69",
        "Hands": "49",
        "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)": "25",
        "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100": "-157.32",
        "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)": "17"
    },
}
```

I need to extract the keys from this data, without knowing this data (as if I havent seen the json), and without changing the json file... it comes as it's shown above.

I have to do this with a js. The keys will change with new json's, and I need to repeat this process and extract the keys to use them in the next script. How do I do this correctly.

I've tried with this:

```
<script src="./Data0012.json">
  var s = require('./Data0012.json');
  var data = JSON.parse(s);
  for (var key in data) {
    var value = data[key];
  }
  console.log(key);
</script>
```

but the console gives me an error with data:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at Data0012.json:2:14)
> attribute

what can I do to solve this. **Help please**.(dont give me negative points)
Edited; Input: Data0012.json
output wanted: Data0012.json's key's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to load json file

> Provide you two ways for reference

❶ Wrap it up to create a Javascript object

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Data0012.json"></script>
```

---

❷ Read file path

```
function loadJSON(filePath, callback) {
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', filePath, true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
}

loadJSON("Data0012.json", function(text){
    const data = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(data);
});
```

### How to get the key of an object

```
Object.keys(obj)
```

### How to get data objects in different scripts

> If you have a server, you can write api to edit and modify your json
> file, and call api in different scripts to get json data, or simply
> use Window.localStorage to keep updated data

```
// Get object key
const keys = Object.keys(obj);

// Stored data
localStorage.setItem('keys', keys);

// Call method to get stored data when in different scripts
const keys = localStorage.getItem('keys');
```

Comment: sorry ... I have not explained correctly ... I cant edit the json ... (I will change de q)

Comment: @javitopo I still don't quite understand what you want, what input you want and what output you want, or provide a more detailed scenario description that will help me understand your problem

Comment: edited; the input is the json file, the output whanted are the json file keys.

Comment: @javitopo Whether the json file is placed on the local hard disk or is it called api to get its data

Comment: @javitopo If you just want keys, both `for (const key in data)` and `Object.keys(obj)` can satisfy this need

Comment: I've tried writing data=Data0012.json   and it gives me an error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: Data0012 is not defined
    at index002.html:58:1                  also, this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I need to extract the keys, to use them in the next script

Comment: You haven't answered me what is the source of the json file? Is Data0012.json the path to your json file? If yes, you can't read it directly like this

Comment: sorry ... I didnt answer. yes, the path now is at the same directory.

Comment: I need to say that I cant change the json file

Comment: @javitopo I re-edited my answer, hope it helps you a little

Comment: I've edited the q, now I reach to an error in the json file, the ':'

Comment: hi, thanks, need more explanation of this.

Comment: where do I write api?

Comment: 0k, done that, I have an error in the json, that I cant modify ... what can I do? the error is the ':' token

Comment: @javitopo Check your Data0012.json syntax content

Comment: I have 1 q: how can I call the for example 2nd and third key?

Comment: You already have a key, so you can directly use the key to get the value. For example, data is your json data, and keys is your key array. To get the value corresponding to the second key, you can use data[keys[1]]

Comment: In the same way, to get the value corresponding to the third key, you can use data[keys[2]]

Comment: hi ... searching in the console, I found other problems. 1st) what do you call (obj)?(its not defined before).

Comment: The obj of Object.keys(obj) refers to the object that stores the content of the json file, and replaces it with its own object

Comment: so, the object is in here: data ... but can call data from outside the function (don't know how or why)?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to extract the keys of the JSON object you can try this**

```js
const data = {
    "-162.65": {
        "Player": "DntFuckwithMeMTFrs",
        "Hands": "44",
        "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)": "13",
        "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100": "-162.65",
        "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)": "50"
    },
    "-162.27": {
        "Player": "paramasivum",
        "Hands": "40",
        "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)": "9",
        "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100": "-162.27",
        "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)": "67"
    },
    "-157.32": {
        "Player": "Fairline69",
        "Hands": "49",
        "(BTN) PFR (2-2,25) (16+)": "25",
        "!!!0 All-In Equity Adjusted BB/100": "-157.32",
        "BH_MTT_3Bet (BB vs BU open)": "17"
    },
}

const keys = Object.keys(data) // ["-162.65","-162.27","-157.32"]
```

Comment: I cant modify the json file ... is there a way to go arround this?

Comment: Can't understand what you mean by 'modify the json file'

Comment: I cant write in the json file ... it comes as it is ... as I wrote it down. ... this means I cant write in the json const data = { ...........

Comment: I've edited, now I reach to another error in the json file (the ':'). do you know how to solve this?